# STM32: storing a map of addresses in an array

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f7

I'm trying to store a map of addresses in an array.

The following code snippet works as expected on my STM32F767ZI, but compiles with a warning...

```
intptr_t addressMap[2];

int* a=NULL;
int* b=NULL;

*a=10;
*b=20;

addressMap[0]=(intptr_t) a;
addressMap[1]=(intptr_t) b;

int* c=addressMap[0];
```

compiles with a warning:

```
initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

at the last line (`int* c=addressMap[0];`).

I also tried `uint32_t` and `int32_t` as the data type of the `addressMap` array. Same warning.

According to this document (http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125009502.htm)
addresses are 32 bit wide (as expected).

How may I write my code without this warning?

Comment: In this case I would just declare addressMap as an array of pointers to integers `int * addressMap[2];` (no cast needed then)

Comment: Tried that also, same warning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How may I write my code without this warning?

as the warning says just add a cast doing

```
int* c = (int*) addressMap[0];
```

to avoid the warning `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

But, I recommend you to not use `intptr_t` but directely `int*` if the goal of *addressMap* is to contains pointers to *int* , thanks to that you do not need cast at all :

```
int * addressMap[2];

int* a=NULL;
int* b=NULL;

*a=10;
*b=20;

addressMap[0] = a;
addressMap[1] = b;

int* c = addressMap[0];
```

Comment: @JohannHorvat you welcome. The less you have cast in code and warnings because of the code, the better it is. I encourage you to compile asking the compiler to produce the max warning level, for instance using _gcc_ do `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra ...`